# show different controllers for one tab depending on some condition

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

When user taps on Favourites tab, I need to show:

1. Introduction of how to add favourite, if there is no favourite
2. Otherwise show the list of favourites

So when user taps on the tab button, I need to check if there is any favourite then decide which controller to use, how do I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the introduction is static, with no significant user interaction, you can place the introduction into a subview that is on top in the view containing the list of favorites. Set its frame size to cover up the favorites list. (It will be dismissed by the user with the code below.) Call this the introductionView. One way to put the introductionView on top is to add that subview last when you create the list-of-favorites view.

In your view controller for your list of favorites, go to viewWillAppear and add these lines:
(If there are already favorites, this assumes the user has been through the introduction.)

```
if (*some test whether there are already favorites on the list*)
    introductionView.hidden = YES;
else
    introductionView.hidden = NO;
```

Add some code to run when the user presses the dismiss button

```
- (void) dismissHit{
    introductionView.hidden = YES;
}
```

This will always show the introductionView when the favorites tab is hit, unless there are some favorites already on the list. Read the [UIView class reference](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html&rct=j&q=uiview%20class%20reference&ei=0wKGTvikNIOKsAL81MSwDw&usg=AFQjCNFEmu_qT5ad_FF-PNR2VnhdCe7ROA&cad=rja) and the [UIViewController class reference](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html&rct=j&q=uiviewcontroller%20class%20reference&ei=8wKGTqr6J8OKsQKLqK2mDw&usg=AFQjCNHk3N-bEEkFuSaj1HLyn9YjNaH0ug&cad=rja). Look at the methods listed to get a better feel what this is doing.
Good luck.